# Finding the common face of clinging soap bubbles using trigonometric functions of angles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to help my daughter with a problem from Stewart's Precalculus book.This problem comes right after law of sines.

When two bubbles cling together in midair, their common surface is part of a sphere whose center D lies on the line passing through the centers of the bubbles (please refer to the figure below) also angles ACB and ACD each have measure 60 degrees

- Show that the radius r of the common surface is given by r = ab / (b - a)
- Find the radius of the common face if the radii of the bubbles are 3cm and 4cm

I could do the second one but after using law of cosines to find length of the segment AB in triangle CBA. That came out as [image: \sqrt{13}]
Then I used law of sines in triangle ABC to find angle CAB = 73.897 degrees

Angle CAD = 180 - angle CAB = 106.1 degrees
angle CDA = 180 - 106.1 - 60 = 13.897 degrees

Then I used law of sines in triangle CAD to find the value of r

But I couldn't make any headway for the first one. Also it seems to me that I don't need law of cosines to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
[image: Diagram]

Comment: When I saw the image, my first guess was that $r$ was the radius of the [Apollonius circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius'_definition_of_a_circle) defined by the points $A,B$ and the ratio $k = \frac{a}{b}$. However, this would give $$r = \frac{ab}{b^2-a^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}$$
I find Stewart's choice of $r$ somewhat arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

By the law of cosines,
$$BD=\sqrt{a^2+r^2-2ar\cos(120)}$$
$$BA=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(60)}$$
$$AD=\sqrt{b^2+r^2-2br\cos(60)}$$
Since $BD=BA+AD$ we now have
$$\sqrt{a^2+r^2-2ar\cos(120)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(60)}+\sqrt{b^2+r^2-2br\cos(60)}$$
Note that $\cos(60)=1/2$ and $\cos(120)=-1/2$. Hence we obtain
$$\sqrt{a^2+r^2+ar}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}+\sqrt{b^2+r^2-br}$$
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%5Csqrt%7Ba%5E2%2Br%5E2%2Bar%7D%3D%5Csqrt%7Ba%5E2%2Bb%5E2-ab%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Bb%5E2%2Br%5E2-br%7D%20for%20r) now gives the solution $r=ab/(a-b)$, although you can prove it by hand if necessary by squaring both sides, isolating the remaining root and then squaring both sides again.

For the second one, just plug in $a=4$ and $b=3$ to obtain $r=12$.

Comment: thank you for the prompt answer! The hint in the problem (which I forgot to mention) is to use law of sines along-with angle θ and 180 - θ have the same sine). Just wondering if there is any easier way to get to r = ab/(a - b)

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

The line $CA$ is angle $\angle{DCB}$ bisector so

$$
\frac{BA}{AD} = \frac{a}{r}
$$

Answer (score 0):

As this is a homework problem, I will just give an outline of the answer. Denote the length of $\overline{AD}$ by $\ell$ and the length of $\overline{BA}$ by $s$.

Step 1: Find nice formulae for $\ell^2, s^2$ in (and at worst quadratic in) $a,b,r$ by using the law of cosines.

Step 2: Use the law of sines, and that $\sin( \angle BAC) = \sin(\angle DAC)$, to show $a/s = r/\ell$.

Step 3: The equation $r^2 = a^2 \ell^2/s^2$ is quadratic in $r$. Show that it has as solutions $r = a, ab/(a-b)$.

Step 4: Figure out why the solution $r=a$ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Considerations of surface tension physics.. differential pressure on either side of wall determine radii of spherical bubble segments

$$ \frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b},~ a<b ~ $$
which is the relation between  curvatures. It is well explained in the link:

[Two bubbles interphase circle radius](https://byjus.com/question-answer/q-in-the-case-when-2-soaps-bubbles-are-attached-the-smaller-soap-is-of/)

$$ \angle BCD= 120^{\circ}$$

and CA is angle bisector at C.

Inserting $(a=3, b=4)$ we get $r=12.$ The angles if required are computed from the Cosine Rule.

If there are *three* coalescing bubbles it will be further interesting to derive and find along similar lines, that each circle tangent at the common vertex makes the same $ \angle 120^{\circ}$ to one another.